# Inequality in the Paley-Wiener Theorem proof

Tags: inequality, fourier-transform

I'm trying to follow the proof of the Paley-Wiener-Schwartz theorem, but I don't know how do I obtain the following inequality:

$$\sum_{|\alpha|\leq N} \sup_{x\in K} |D^\alpha(\chi_\delta e^{-i<x,\zeta>})|  \leq C' \exp(H(Im (\zeta))+\delta|Im(\zeta)|)\sum_{\alpha\leq N} \delta^{-|\alpha|}(1+|\zeta|)^{N-|\alpha|}$$

Where

$H$ is the supporting function of the convex compact set K.

$\chi_\delta \in C^{\infty}_0(K_\delta)$, $\chi_\delta=1$  in $K_{\delta/2}$

$K_\delta=\{x+y; x\in K,|y|\leq \delta\}$

I also have a estimative for $|D^\alpha \chi_\delta|\leq C_\alpha \delta^{-|\alpha|}$

I tried expanding the derivative in the left side using the Leibniz formula, but I can't see where come the $\exp(\delta |Im(\zeta)|$ term in the right side of the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Leibniz formula,
\begin{align}
|D^\alpha (\chi_\delta(x) e^{-i\langle x, \zeta \rangle})|
&= \left| \sum_{\beta \leq \alpha} \binom{\alpha}{\beta} \left(\partial^{\alpha-\beta} e^{-i\langle x, \zeta \rangle}\right) \left( \partial^{\beta}\chi_\delta (x) \right)  \right|\\
&\leq \sum_{\beta \leq \alpha} \binom{\alpha}{\beta} |\zeta^{\alpha-\beta}| |e^{-i\langle x, \zeta \rangle}| |\partial^{\beta}\chi_\delta (x)|\\
&\leq C_\alpha \, 2^{|\alpha|}\, e^{\langle x, \text{Im}\zeta\rangle}\sum_{\beta \leq \alpha}  |\zeta|^{|\alpha|-|\beta|}  \delta^{-|\beta|}.
\end{align}
Taking the supremum over $x \in K_\delta$ gives
\begin{align}
\sup_{x \in K_\delta}|D^\alpha (\chi_\delta(x) e^{-\langle x, \zeta \rangle})|
&\leq C_\alpha' \exp\left({H_{K_\delta}(\text{Im}\zeta)}\right) \sum_{\beta \leq \alpha} \ |\zeta|^{|\alpha|-|\beta|}  \delta^{-|\beta|}\\
&\leq C_\alpha' \exp\left({H_{K}(\text{Im}\zeta) + |\delta||\text{Im}\zeta|}\right) \sum_{\beta \leq \alpha}
|\zeta|^{|\alpha|-|\beta|}  \delta^{-|\beta|}.
\end{align} 
Can you finish?

Comment: Sorry, I can see the sum in the right forming something like $(1+|\zeta|)^{|\alpha|}$ but I can't see it becoming something like $(1+|\zeta|)^{N-|\alpha|}$

Comment: @tererecomchimarrao Observe that $$ |\zeta|^{|\alpha|-|\beta|} \leq (1+|\zeta|)^{|\alpha|-|\beta|}. $$